# How to get local disk file path in file upload using java? If it is form based web application...?

Tags: java

I am using MultipartFile to upload file by using `multipartFile.transferTo(new java.io.File(saveDirectory,fileName));`. How MultipartFile getting file path. In file upload we will get only file name.

My code is:

```
if (null != files && files.size() > 0) {
    for (MultipartFile multipartFile : files) {
        fileName = multipartFile.getOriginalFilename();
        multipartFile.transferTo(new java.io.File(saveDirectory, fileName));

        System.out.println("kkkkkkkkk" + fileName);
        nameoffile = fileName;
        fileNames.add(fileName);

        //Handle file content - multipartFile.getInputStream()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import com.oreilly.servlet.MultipartRequest;
```

You can use `MultipartRequest m=new MultipartRequest(request,"d:/new");`

Answer (score -1):

`MultipartFile.getOriginalFilename` may contain path information from the client filesystem depending on the browser you are using. Most browsers like Firefox and Chrome will include include filename without path information. IE at one time did include the complete path information but not sure if that's still true with newer versions of IE.

For more information, see the [MultipartFile reference documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/multipart/MultipartFile.html#getOriginalFilename--).